# Minimum requirements for Ecto NoSQL adapter

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, tirexs

We are looking for a best possible way to incorporate Elastic into our project while preserving all the goodness that `phoenix-ecto` has to offer, i.e. changeset validations and `Phoenix.HTML.Form` compatibility.

With Ecto 2.0 it looks like that this task should be easier than ever.

So the questions are:

- Is there a skeleton for a NoSQL Ecto adapter?
- What preliminary requirements? Pitfalls?
- What are minimum requirements for such adapter to handle embbeds?

Comment: Those are three substantial questions each on their own. Maybe you want to start with just the first question and go from there?

Comment: Probably that makes sense. Actually, after reading the blog post we decided to  start with a thin wrapper over `Tirexs.HTTP` and see if it will make sense to add Ecto compatibility layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Michal Muskala wrote a nice article about creating a NoSQL adapter for Ecto:

[Blog Post](http://michal.muskala.eu/2015/07/07/creating-ecto-adapters.html)